# Parse a list to get exact value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ldap, ldap3

I am trying to query Active directory through LDAP to list groups but I get more information than I need. How can I parse the result to only get all group names. For example: `LOCAL_java_read` and the others and not the rest from the result.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
server = Server('xxx', port=389, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'username', 'password', auto_bind=True, raise_exceptions=True)
conn.search('OU=Groups,OU=CH,DC=google,DC=com', '(objectclass=group)')
groups=conn.entries
print (groups)
```

Result:

```
[DN: CN=LOCAL_java_read,OU=Groups,OU=CH,DC=google,DC=com - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2019-03-27T14:22:08.072330
, DN: CN=LOCAL_python_read,OU=Groups,OU=CH,DC=google,DC=com - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2019-03-27T14:22:08.072330
, DN: CN=LOCAL_php_read,OU=Groups,OU=CH,DC=google,DC=com - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2019-03-27T14:22:08.072330]
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected result?

Comment: what is your desired result ?

Comment: My desired result from the result code is to only get the group name which is `LOCAL_java_read`, `LOCAL_python_read` and `LOCAL_php_read`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract group names from the individual group entries using regex:

```
import re
stripped_groups = [re.sub(r'^.+? CN=([^,\s]+),?.*$', r'\1', str(entry)) for entry in groups]
print(stripped_groups)
```

Although I assume a @Nathan McCoy's answer might ultimately lead to a cleaner and better solution.

Comment: I agree. However the ldap search/filtering does not seem to work. So this could also be a good try.

Comment: I get this when I ran it: `expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: so this means the strings in the list are bytestrings and we have to convert them before using with regex. I adapted my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Instead of `str(entry)`, you could also use `entry.decode()`. In any case it might be worth checking out https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str or https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Active directory structures its attributes but I believe you can just use a wildcard `*` to get the groups by changing the search.

```
conn.search('OU=Groups,OU=CH,DC=google,DC=com', '(&(objectClass=group)(CN=*))')
```

[Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax) has information about LDAP search filters which are most likely relevant to AD. There are some examples about [Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax#wildcards)

Comment: why not just try `CN=*` without the `objectClass`. regardless, search filters will work. you just need to make the right one.

Comment: Hmm, that did not work either. So looking for a solution here.

Comment: sorry, cant be more help without a real AD environment. There are command line tools you can test until you have what you are looking for such as `ldapsearch`